# How to add other info to main page of mobile app?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, interaction-design, mobile-application, interface

This is what our app looks like:

[image]

For each row I would like to add the *amenities* for the particular gas station (ie. "parking", "bathroom", etc). For example, "Rocket Fuel" has parking, bathroom, and a mechanic.

How can I add this information to the list without disrupting the main purpose of the app (display gas prices)?

People use the app because it tells them the gas prices, but I would like to give them more information without altering the existing flow of the app, or its primary purpose.

My biggest concern is that the list will be too crowded, or maybe adding the information will somehow affect what the users think about the app.

As a sidenote, an app like Gasbuddy (which is similar to our app but doesn't compete with us) also displays this additional information with icons, but when a user clicks on a gas station. For some reason, gasbuddy decided not to add the icons to the main page.

Comment: Do you have any examples of designs you've tried or sketched out?

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any issue with adding **small** **low-profile** icons at the bottom on the main page. Icons in Black or Grey or your theme color in a light shade should not disrupt the overall look.

[Priceline](https://www.priceline.com/) uses small icons on their app, and uses those icons with text on their website. In your case I would suggest the following:

**1-** On the **main page** where you display multiple gas stations with prices...etc. Use small low-profile icons. They **would not crowd** your page and they offer a great piece of **info**. See this example:

[image]

**2-** Now If you want to make sure each icon's meaning is clear to your users, On the **gas station page** (after one is selected), use the icons with a text to explain any unclear icon's meaning. See this example:

[image]

This way you achieve your goals by providing a piece of important info without crowding the page. Moreover, If there are concerns that icons selected may have a vague meaning, users can learn their meanings seeing the text on a specific gas station page.

Comment: Thanks. What do you think of using small low-profile icons (like you suggested) but with different colors instead of black or gray?

Comment: This was my first thought too.

Comment: I actually said: "Black or Grey or your theme color in a light shade should not disrupt the overall look". A color that works is fine. I said black and grey so the icons are not the main focus as that is one of your concerns.

Comment: i was checking priceline's  mobile app, and I don't think they use the icons in the mobile app.

Comment: I got the screenshot from their mobile app the day i saw your question and I just checked again, they have them. However, whether they have them or not, that should not affect your decision. I did not provide them as the example to follow, I provided a screenshot from their app as an idea that I find useful and fits your requirement and answers your question!

Comment: Search for a hotel and check the Express Deals page on priceline